# Return list of Func as single Func

Tags: c#

I have a list of func

```
class SomeClass
{
  List<Func<int, bool>> _funcList;

}
```

I want to write a function in the class to return all the items in the list as a single func

```
Func<int, bool> GetAllTrueConditions()
{
  //for each item in _funcList do AND and return
}
```

So that I can do below

```
Collection.Filter = obj.GetAllTrueConditions();
```

Comment: You want to return multiple times in one function call?

Comment: Delegates are probably your best bet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

Comment: `_funcList.All(f => f(someParameter))`

Comment: Are you looking for this? `return i => _funcList.All(x => x(i));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to return a lambda function. To call all functions from a list you would use

```
_funcList.All(func => func(5));
```

We no can construct a lambda to execute the statement above:

```
var callAll = integerVal => _funcList.All(func => func(integerVal));
```

Complete example

```
class SomeClass
{
    List<Func<int, bool>> _funcList;

    Func<int, bool> GetAllTrueConditions()
    {
        //for each item in _funcList do AND and return
        return integerVal => _funcList.All(func => func(integerVal));
    }
}
```